# Can't connect from my Angular app to ASP.Net server SignalR

Tags: asp.net, angular, sockets, signalr, .net-framework-version

I use ASP.Net framework to host the socket server. I created a Hub using SignalR, i ran it and then tried to connect to it from my angular app but recieved this error:

```
Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

There are no more details.
I Enabled CORS with this code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR("/Art", new HubConfiguration());
        }
```

and in the hub:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ArtHub : Hub
    {
    ....
    }
```

I will highly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

In configuration of your server use this to see detailed error info:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});
```

Use SignalR Hub endpoint like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ArtHub>("/art");
});
```

Comment: i am using .NET framework and not core, so i don't have these